# Stripe Custom Checkout Issue with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm currently creating a job board where when a customer posts a job board they pay for it in one form and it will then post the job and charge there card all at once.

First, I used the standard Stripe Checkout button along with my listings form and it submitted both my form and took payment.

Then I tried customizing the Stripe Checkout button using the custom docs [**found here**](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) but I can't seem to understand what I'm missing.

Now when I click on the button it pops up like normal but when I submit the button my Rails form doesn't create nor does it charge Stripe.

**listings_controller.rb**

```
def create
  p @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
  charge_error = nil

  p @listing.valid?
  p @listing.errors

  if @listing.valid?
    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :card => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer => customer.id,
        :amount => @amount,
        :description => 'New Job Posting',
        :currency => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      p 'rescue'
      p e
      charge_error = e.message
    end

    if charge_error
      p 'change error not nil'
      p charge_error
      flash[:error] = charge_error
      render :new
    else
      p 'trying to save listing'
      p @listing.save
      redirect_to @listing
    end
  else
    p 'listing not valid'
    flash[:error] = 'one or more errors in your orders'
    render :new
  end
end
```

**listings/_form.html.erb**

```
//Top of the page //
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button class='btn btn-block btn-primary' id='customButton'>
  Pay and Post Your Job Posting!
</button>

<% end %>

<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "pk_test_iSItYFJUx04fB9Ax6yGQjRDP",
    image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png",
    name: "Example Name",
    description: "Pro Subscription ($29 per month)",
    panelLabel: "Subscribe",
    allowRememberMe: false,
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
      token.id
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    handler.open({
      name: 'Example Name #2',
      description: 'Subscripe ($99/monthly)',
      amount: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation:
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

If you need any other info please ask. Thank you!

Comment: Look at the output of your rails server and your javascript console. One of them will probably give you more information. Is it even posting to your rails server? If so is it doing anything? Is it erroring?

Comment: When I fill out the payment form nothing happens in my server logs. Although, when I refresh the page and click on the button I see there is an error It's '<Stripe::CardError: (Status 402) (Request req_kIesUxNbPgbABQ) Cannot charge a customer that has no active card>' error. But it doesn't ever load the stripe popup payment form.

Comment: You need to replace `function(token) { token.id }` with code that sends that `token.id` to your backend.  I'd use AJAX.

Comment: Alright, I will try this out.

Comment: @korben you had the correct answer. How would I give you credit?

Comment: @miklki14567 - Just enjoy using Stripe.  I work for Stripe and giving you good answers is part of my job.  :)